# VB.NET WebBrowser control not decode Unicode code

Tags: html, vb.net, unicode, webbrowser-control

I'm in trouble to display an HTML string then contains Unicode characters in the form `\u00xx`. This characters are not decoded and are displayed as is.
For instance a string as `"abcdefg \003ci\003eTEXT"` is not decoded to `"abcdefg <i>TEXT`.
I would like to avoid a brute replacing of each encoded characters. There is a way?

Thanks

Update
The file json is UTF8 encoded.
It's composed of row as

```
"1199" : "Item order \u003ci\u003e123456\u003c/i\u003e"
```

Json file is deserialized to a Dictionary<Of String, String> and the value is sent to a webbrowser contro. The sample row should be decoded to

`"1199" : "Item order <i>123456</i>"`

Comment: Have you determined why you're getting a string that contains Unicode codepoints like that? Wrong encoding? What's sending it? Are you *interpreting* the content somehow?

Comment: I read that string from a json file coming from a VBA Macro Excel. I have no control over it...

Comment: Show how you're reading it then. -- The content is probably encoded using Encoding.Default (the Local encoding, related to the Language used to install Office / Excel)

Comment: Dim jsonText As String
            jsonText = File.ReadAllText("labels.json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            labelsLang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(jsonText)

Comment: Please, add any code you have to the question's body, not in comments. -- You're using UTF8 to read that file, check the actual encoding, as mentioned. You should also post the code that generates the file you're reading. -- Saving a file using UTF8 as encoding in Excel, may not actually generate an UTF8 encoded file.